# After configuring exim and dovecot am getting below error while restarting exim in centos

Tags: dovecot, exim

iam new to this configuration,please help me..

Exim configuration error in line 63 of /etc/exim/exim.conf:
  main option "dovecot_login" unknown

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ServerFault is not a "Read My Error Messages For Me as a Service" provider

Comment: ok... this was my very first question, i am sorry for my off-topic question.

Answer (score 1):

It clearly states that in the `exim.conf` file, specifically line 63, the option `dovecot_login` doesn't exist. Double check that the version of exim supports that configuration item.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information in the question, but this question just might be a duplicate of [Exim authentication using Dovecot driver](https://serverfault.com/questions/270221/exim-authentication-using-dovecot-driver) (except that you are using centos, of course)